# Removing a quantity from multiple rows in a database

Tags: mysql

Here is my table structure:
`table`.`id` (auto increment; primary key)
`table`.`qty` ( possible values: 0 - 1000 )

Rows:

```
+----+-----+
| id | qty |
+----+-----+
|  1 |   0 |
|  2 |   5 |
|  3 |   5 |
|  4 |  10 |
+----+-----+
```

I want to decrease the quantity available by 12.  Meaning, the new result should be:
**Edit: I probably should have specified all these numbers are arbitrary.  They could be anything.**

```
+----+-----+
| id | qty |
+----+-----+
|  1 |   0 |
|  2 |   0 |
|  3 |   0 |
|  4 |   8 |
+----+-----+
```

Right now, I do the following:

1. `SELECT id, qty FROM table WHERE qty > 0 LIMIT 12`
2. Filter through all the data to figure out what qty to remove from each row
3. Use a PDO prepared statement to mass update the affected rows:

   ```
   UPDATE `table` SET qty = ? WHERE id = ?`
   ```

My question:  Is there a way to do this all in MySQL?

Comment: How do you decide the allocation of the 12 across the four different values of id? Take them in order? Subtract from all equally? The two answers provided so far don't actually get you the behavior you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SET @q = 12;

UPDATE `table`
SET qty = CONCAT(GREATEST(qty - @q, 0), LEFT(@q := @q - LEAST(qty, @q), 0))
ORDER BY id;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07928/6).

Comment: From reading about this now, my understanding is that this is going to go through each row, for each row it will do a true false statement:  If qty - 12 is greater than 0, it will return whatever that difference is; otherwise it will return 0.  
I would need it to just go one step further and turn 12 into a number that is decrementing.  I think you use :quantity but i'm lost from there.

Comment: Hi, I can't get this to work.  The comma is causing an error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@q := @q - LEAST(`inv_layer`.`qty_avail`, @q) 
ORDER BY `inv_layer`.`id`' at line 1

Comment: @phpmeh: Hmm... sorry about that... I didn't expect `UPDATE` to *require* every assignment to be to a column... the updated code above has been tested and works!

Comment: Fantastic.  I like your CONCAT( , Left( , 0 ) ) work around.  I'm still learning, but that's pretty clever.

Comment: Answering questions with ready-to-use answers and no guidance leads only to [more questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104914/returning-a-sql-variable-to-php/11105034).