# Returning a sql variable to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following query:

```
    SET @q = 12;  
    UPDATE `table` 
    SET qty = CONCAT(GREATEST(qty - @q, 0), LEFT(@q := @q - LEAST(qty, @q), 0)) 
    ORDER BY id;
```

(Go vote eggyal up for the great query here: [Removing a quantity from multiple rows in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557492/removing-a-quantity-from-multiple-rows-in-a-database) )

I am running the query (without preparing in this case) through OOP PDO / MySQL.

I want to pass the value of the @q back to PHP or any flag really if @q did not get to 0.  I'm not sure how to accomplish this.  If anyone is able to point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select it, as you would anything else:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT @q AS q") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['q'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work:

```
$res = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query( "SELECT @q" ) );
print_r( $res );
```